CSS Specificity issues in Nextjs 14.2.4, clsx environments
CSS Specificity is not working as expected.
The className passed in from the parent component is built first and overwritten by the existing button style, as expected.

vanilla-extract, module css both give the same result
function SomeButton() {
  return <Button className={styles.someButton}/> // I want this class to override the button's style
}

export const Button: PolymorphicComponent<ButtonProps, "button"> = forwardRef(
  ...
  ) => {
    //...

    return (
      <Box
        as={as}
        ref={ref}
        disabled={disabled}
        data-disabled={disabled}
        className={cn([
          styles.button({
            variant,
            block,
            size,
          }),

          className,
        ])}
        {...rest}
      />
    );
  },
);


import { ElementType, forwardRef, ReactNode } from "react";

export const Box: PolymorphicComponent<BoxProps> = forwardRef(
   //...
  ) => {
    const { as, ...rest } = props;
    const Component = as ?? "div";
    return <Component ref={ref}  {...rest} />;
  },
);


import clsx, { type ClassValue } from "clsx";

export function cn(...className: ClassValue[]) {
  return clsx(className);
}

